# How to show specified x-axis label when scale in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have chart by chart = new Highcharts.StockChart and the xAxis is 'datetime' with a list of value. In the xAxis, most of the value is in format xx'yy but there are some date has key alias like Alpha-xx'yy. During horzontial scale xAxis, the label will auto hide some date but I'd like to let it always show the key date like Alpha-xx'yy when people change the period.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but you should be able to use xAxis.tickPositioner for adding some fixed tick positions to your chart. You can find very simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/99gnsnd9/

Comment: I have a 3 years data by week of each x-axis, so that is around 150 of x-axis. on specified week, I give one aligns, like alpha-2016ww10, beta-2016ww25, pv-2016ww40. when user do the scrolling of x-axis, it may show 2016ww09 but I'd like it to show the alpha-2016ww10 as it has key milestone information.